# Tire and Tube size mismatch

Tags: tire, innertube

I have a tire with `24x2.125` written on it, and the new inner tube which I'm planning to install `24x2.175-3.0` Is this too big for the tire and can be prone to punctures etc. or should be OK? It is a conventional bicycle.

**UPDATE** - I ended up buying a tube the same size as the tire and it fits perfectly. I failed to install `24x2.175` tube because a piece of it was sticking out, I worried that the tube would fold inside the tire and would wear off quickly.

Comment: Give it a try.    Main problem is fold in the tube.

Comment: It would be nice to have a smaller one.  In general, given a choice between a too-large tube and a similarly too-small one, I prefer the too-small one.   The main danger is the oversize tube folding up inside the tire, leading to lumps in the tire and eventually leakage due to cracks in the tube.  In your case, though, the mismatch is too small to really worry about.

Comment: Just nit-picky - the Tyre/Tire is the rubber hoop on the outside that touches the road surface and its job is to protect and constrain the inflated tube.  The Tube is the doughnut of butyl rubber that sits inside the tyre, and its job is to hold the air.  I've edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

If its unopened you might be able to take it back to the shop and swap for the right size, but the difference between 2.125" and 2.175" is 0.05" which is only 2.3 % smaller so it would probably work fine.

There may be a bit more tube than you strictly need, and this could make pinching the tube easier when fitting it, so do take care.

Otherwise, a tube is probably one of the cheapest parts on a bike, and buying another won't break your wallet.

Comment: A lot of inner tubes are labelled with an interval of diameters, and those intervals are a lot wider than 2.125-2.175". For example, https://www.decathlon.es/lote-2-camaras-mtb-26x175-210-schraeder-id_3314575.html is labelled 1.7-2.2". Therefore your size mismatch seems to be tiny.

Comment: OK I plugged in an incorrect number